# Filter templates by ChoiceField - Django

Tags: python, django

consider this model on Django:

```
class My_model(models.Model):
    my_choices = { '1:first' 2:second'}
    myfield1=CharField()
    myfield2=CharField(choices=my_choices)
```

Then on my form:

```
class My_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = My_model
    fields = ['myfield1', 'myfield2']
```

My views:

```
def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = My_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = My_form()

    return render(request, 'form/myform.html', {'form': form})
```

On my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<form action="/tlevels/" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

On my base.html, I will load this template like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white" style="margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">Status</div>
<div class="form-row" style="margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:20px;">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
    {{ form.myfield1|as_crispy_field }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
    {{ form.myfield2|as_crispy_field }}
  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" style="margin-left:20px;">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

What I want, is to have 2 other different templates, with whatever difference on them, and load them depending on the choice made on the ChoiceField, I guess that one way could be on the view, by adding some kind of conditional, and load a different template (html file).

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to load one of the two templates in the view/template that produces the form? Or use a variable after the form is POSTed? If the first cases, you would probably have to use JavaScript. In the second, you could insert the value from the form into the context and use something like ``{% include myfield2_value %}``. Assuming the value is stored somewhere for later use.

Comment: After the form is POSTed yes, after it has set whatever value from choicefield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use `{% include %}` with a variable.

```py
def some_view_after_post(request):
    # ... lookup value of myfield2 ...
    return render(request, "path/to/after_post.html", {'myfield2: myfield2})
```

The in the `after_post.html` template:

```html
<!-- include a template based on user's choice -->
<div class="user-choice">
{% include myfield2 %}
</div>
```

You'll want to make sure there is no possible way the user can inject an erroneous choice. For example, make sure the value of myfield2 choice is valid before adding it to the context.